# Set dataframe to series or show nth label

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matlab

Whenever I plot a dataset to a bar plot, the x axis labels overload with labels. How can I change the datatype of the x axis from the dataframe or how can I display every nth label?

Here is my code:

```
# Import statements for the packages to be used.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Loading the data and having a look at the first few lines
df = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')
df.head()

# Replace 0 with NaN (Not a Number)
df['budget'].replace(0, np.NAN, inplace=True)
df['runtime'].replace(0, np.NAN, inplace=True)

# Drop all rows with null values (NaN)
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)

# Drop all columns not required for investigation
df = df.drop(['id', 'imdb_id', 'revenue', 'cast', 'homepage', 'director', 'tagline', 
'keywords', 'overview', 'genres', 'production_companies', 'vote_count', 'vote_average', 
'release_date', 'budget_adj', 'revenue_adj'], axis=1)

budget_grp = df.groupby(['budget'])
budget_grp['popularity'].agg(['median', 'mean'])
# Setting mean popularity to variable budget_pop.
budget_pop = budget_grp['popularity'].mean()
# Bar plot with x as budget and y as average popularity.
budget_pop.plot(kind='bar' ,x='budget', y='popularity', figsize=(20,10), xlabel='Budget in 
Dollars', ylabel='Average Popularity', rot=0,  legend=True)
```

I have tried enumerate but don't know where to fit that in. I have also tried creating a function to find nth and I have tried changing my dataframe to integer but they always error.

[image]

Follow-up to answer below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom xticks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':np.arange(1,1001,1), 'y':np.random.randint(1,1000,1000)})
ax = df.plot(kind='bar' ,x='x', y='y', figsize=(20,10))
min_value_in_x = 1
max_value_in_x = 1000
x_ticks = np.arange(min_value_in_x, max_value_in_x, 100)
ax.set(xticks=x_ticks, xticklabels=x_ticks)
plt.show()
```

Comment: At what point would I integrate this?

Comment: set ax = budget_pop.plot(your_parameters_here) then follow the x_ticks logic from my answer

Comment: I've got the chart mostly working now. However, because the budget numbers range from 0 to 650,000,000 I can't get the axis to scale with the bars. The updated plot is in the body of my question

Comment: You should use max_value_in_x from your budget column instead of setting it to 1000